# How to add an array to a bitfield struct?

Tags: c, struct, bit-fields

I tried to use bit fields in a struct for some values which only need one or two bits instead of a whole byte.

My code is:

```
struct s_rdata {
    signed int      p0:28; 
    signed int      p1:28; 
    signed int      p2:28; 
    unsigned int    d0:17; 
    unsigned int    d1:17; 
    unsigned int    d2:17; 
    unsigned char   data1:1; 
    unsigned char   data2:1; 
} rdata;
```

So, you might see that there are variables named `p0` - `p2`, `d0` - `d2` and `data1` - `data2`.

I'd now like to have those in an array. However, none of this lines does work:

```
signed int p[3]:28; 
signed int p:28[3];
```

Can't I add an array to a bitfield list, an array of `signed int` only needing 28 bits per entry?

Answer (score 4):

No, you cannot have an array of bitfields, nor a bitfield whose base type is an array type.  The latter doesn't even make sense.  The former would be counter-productive, as you would lose any space efficiency gained by using bitfields in the first place.

You can have an array of a `struct`s with a single bitfield member:

```
struct container {
  signed int bitfield:7;
} array[3];
```

but again, you would lose any space efficiency associated with the bitfield use.

You can create an array of any `struct` type, of course, including those with multiple bitfield members.  In that case, you may achieve some internal space efficiency within the individual structures, but you will likely see padding at the end of each one that reduces the overall space efficiency of the array.

Ultimately, unless your program's memory consumption is excessive for its target environment, I strongly recommend that you forget about bitfields.  They will complicate your life for an uncertain gain of uncertain importance, and that gain will likely be offset by a performance degradation (of uncertain magnitude and importance).

Should you eventually decide that the program really is using too much memory, then be certain to *test* any change you make to see how much improvement it yields, and at what cost.

Comment: Would ***[pragma pack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa273913%28v=VS.60%29.aspx)*** statements help with the space inefficiencies if going with struct arrays?

Comment: @ryyker, maybe.  The details of the effects of `#pragma pack` are implementation specific.  Where it has any effect at all, specific uses might or might not prevent the compiler from laying out structs with internal or trailing padding, at the cost of possibly causing members to be misaligned.  Unless you are trying to map a `struct` type to a specific, externally-defined data pattern, it is usually better to just lay out the members manually from largest alignment requirement to smallest; this typically avoids any internal padding being introduced, but there may still be trailing padding.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @John's assessment with respect to space  inefficiencies, but that notwithstanding, here is an idea to contain contents of a bit field within struct array:

```
typedef struct
{
  int A : 16;
  int B : 16;
} Struct1;

typedef struct
{
  Struct1 B;//bitfield struct
  int array[10];//combined with array (of any legal type)
}
```

Here is an example of populating array with contents of bit struct:

```
typedef struct {
    signed int      p0:28; 
    signed int      p1:28; 
    signed int      p2:28; 
    unsigned int    d0:17; 
    unsigned int    d1:17; 
    unsigned int    d2:17; 
    unsigned char   data1:1; 
    unsigned char   data2:1; 
} RDATA; 


typedef struct {
    int A[3];
    unsigned int B[3];
    unsigned char C[2];
} ARRAY;

RDATA rdata = {//initialize instance of RDATA with data
    28,
    28,
    28,
    17,
    17,
    17,
    1,
    1
};

int WriteToArray(ARRAY *a);

int main(void)
{
    ARRAY a;
    WriteToArray(&a);//populate array with RDATA values

    //ARRAY is now populated with bitfield values;
    a.A[0];
    a.A[1];
    //and so on

    return 0;
}

WriteToArray(ARRAY *a)
{
    a->A[0]=rdata.p0;//using values initialized above
    a->A[1]=rdata.p1;
    a->A[2]=rdata.p2;
    a->B[0]=rdata.d0;
    a->B[1]=rdata.d1;
    a->B[2]=rdata.d2;
    a->C[0]=rdata.data1;
    a->C[1]=rdata.data2;
    return 0;
}
```

You can also experiment with ***[pragma pack](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Aa273913%28v=VS.60%29.aspx)*** statements to look at effects on space, but refer to @John's comment under your post for additional considerations regarding pragma and spacing.